# Android Link to Market from inside another app

Tags: android, google-play

I am building many apps for Android and wish to have a menu button in the apps that basically opens a list of my other apps in the Android Market.

Is there a way to create an intent and have the Android market pop up with a search (of my company) in the market so users can buy other apps?

ian

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there is a [documented `Intent` syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) for that (`http://market.android.com/search?q=pub:<Developer Name>` or `market://search?q=pub:<Developer Name>`).

Comment: is there an updated link for google play or is it still "market"

Comment: @gregm: Looks like it is still `market`: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know if this still works? I have been trying on a Galaxy S 3 with Play Store 3.7.15 and it doesn't work if I include "pub:" but works fine if I just put the publisher name as the query. I don't like doing it that way though since other stuff could essentially turn up.

Comment: Just the updated link: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Comment: @ CommonsWare, how can i open an app, from other than google playstore (from china, where we have many app stores)

Answer (score 67):

Even better to use "market://details" instead of "market://search":

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Then it opens directly the details page of the app. With search it shows a single search result and the user has to do an additional click to get to the detail page.

Comment: simplified version for Android Studio ```startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));```

Answer (score 4):

The intent action would be view, and uri the market url/uri.

Like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:<developer name>") ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to launch a `URL Intent` with your application's package name in it.
User will get popup with list of installed **Browsers** + **Play Store** app in which he can view your target app.

```
String appPackageName = "com.example.android";
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Above code is tested and works as expected on Play Store version 4.1.6

Answer (score 2):

On my real devices Sony Xperia Pro and PocketBook tablet, even when you put a link to play web store e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop
It will ask if you want to open it in the default browser or in the Play market. 
If you select Play market - application is shown as expected.
Did not test it with intent, tested with Autolink from TextView.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch(item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.adfree:
             final String appPackageName = "com.zooohooo.noads"; // Can also use getPackageName(), as below
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
             return true;
         case R.id.rate:
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));
             return true;
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```