# Single Android Application for multiple units

Tags: android

Can I create an apk file dynamically & brand a generic android application for specific companies / groups ?

I want to create a website where users put their company logo & some other detail & get an android app (link to play store or apk file directly??) that is branded specifically for them.

Comment: yes, you can do this dynamically...

Comment: Yes you can do that see these links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923265/android-how-do-i-open-another-app-from-my-app

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964819/start-android-market-from-app

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442366/android-link-to-market-from-inside-another-app

Answer (score 1):

afaik, the easiest way would be several eclipse projects, having their own manifest/res folder, but pointing on the same src folder