# Redirect app from free app to paid app in other developer id

Tags: google-play

I am living in country which is not supported google play merchant register, but I knew one of developer in country that supported google play merchant register.

Let's say: Developer "A" for not support google play merchant and "B" for supported google play merchant

So, I want to build 2 apps, Lite version for Developer "A" non google play merchant and I redirected from "A" to purchase a full version of app in Developer "B". So if we do this way, it's violation to Google Play Store or not? Because Developer "A" & Developer "B" is difference people.

Many thanks for your kindly answer.

Best Regards,
Vira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to other apps no issue as long as you are taking permission from users to redirect to other app.. Directly redirecting ( in background ) or without taking user permission will result in banning your original app.

Refer to Google Developer Policy Center. https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/

Here is example link on how to link to other app. [Android Link to Market from inside another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442366/android-link-to-market-from-inside-another-app)