# Can we redirect user to other developer apps from our app?

Tags: google-play

I am developing Android app but inside my app I want to redirect user to other developer apps by click on button. My question is:
Is it against to Play Store policy or not?

Appreciated for your kindly help.

Best Regards,
Virak

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about google's policies, and not programming. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic.

Comment: It's also basically a duplicate of [this question that you've already asked and accepted an answer for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817563/redirect-app-from-free-app-to-paid-app-in-other-developer-id) and which is also off-topic.